# Android Espresso - Closing the SearchView

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, searchview, android-espresso

I'm working on Espresso tests for Android and for one of my actions I want to search a list using a SearchView, select an item and then navigate back to the previous screen (by closing the searchview and then pressing the up button).

I've tried some things to access the up/collapse button of the SearchView to close it (that don't work):

- `onView(withContentDescription(R.string.abc_action_bar_up_description))`
- `onView(withId(R.id.search_close_btn))`
- `onView(withId(R.id.home))`
- `onView(withId(R.id.homeAsUp))`
- `onView(withId(R.id.collapseActionView))`
- `Espresso.pressBack()` (to just navigate back)

I'm hoping someone might know some way to access and close this button, because I have no idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparantly I had to press the back button twice to navigate out of it, so if anyone would like to know, you need to use `Espresso.pressBack();` twice to get out of the search menu.

Answer (score 1):

The correct id is R.id.search_close_btn

```
onView(withId(R.id.search_close_btn)).perform(click())
```

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem of accessing this up/collapse button and by reading the hierarchy of components I found out that this button has the content description of 'Collapse'. So using the following solved the problem for me:

`onView(withContentDescription(androidx.appcompat.R.string.abc_toolbar_collapse_description)).perform(click())`